# stack-share place sublime in devops

Tags: sublimetext3, devops

I am confused that how stack share  place sublime in DevOps while its editor
any idea
thanks

here is the link https://stackshare.io/devops
[image: https://stackshare.io/devops]

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a direct relation between sublime and devops, while sublime has tools that can aid you in triggering a ci/cd pipeline, sublime per se has nothing to do with it, nor any other text editor.